# How to Add 301 Redirect Code to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to add 301 redirect for few html pages on my website. My htaccess file already has a lot of code. How to add 301 redirect without messing up the htaccess file.

Here's what it looks like.

```
# turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/

# only detect smart phone devices if we are not on mobile site
# to prevent redirect looping
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.easydestination.net$

# a bunch of smart phone devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "windows ce|epoc|opera|mini|nitro" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "audiovox|blackberry|ericsson,"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|dange"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\."[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC,OR]

# redirect google mobile bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "googlebot-mobile"[NC]

# if the request is from any one of the above devices
# redirect to mobile site'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://m.easydestination.net%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]
```

Comment: What do you want to redirect?

Comment: mysite.com/feedback.html to mysite.com/contact.html. Similarly mysite.com/nyc.html to mysite.com/new_york_city.html. These are just couple of examples.